# output in visual studio is considerably different to firefox

Tags: html

i'm a beginner with html, experimenting with list, unordered list and break tags, and when comparing the html in visual studio to firefox they're completely different to one another. Here is the html code:

```
<body>


        <div class="style1">


        <strong>TID</strong> Book Club<br />

        </div>

        <div>

  <p>Join our Book Club!!</p>

   <p> <span class="style2">We've got some superb bargains - here's a few:</span><br /></p>

   <ul>
   <li><strong>JAVA How to Program (6th Ed)</strong></li>
    PJ & HM Deitel<br />
    ISBN: 0-13-129014-2<br />
       <em>£39.99</em><br />
    </ul> 

    <ul>
   <li><strong>Teach Yourself UML</strong></li>
    J Schmuller<br />
    ISBN: 0-67-232238-2<br />
       <em>£9.99</em><br />
    </ul>


    <ul>
    <li><strong>Practical Business Systems Development using SSADM</strong></li>
     Weaver, N Lambrou & M Walkley<br />
    ISBN: 0-27-365575-2<br />
        <em>£34.99 </em> <br />
    </ul>

    Contact us for more crazy prices!!
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as very odd:

```
<ul> 
   <li><strong>JAVA How to Program (6th Ed)</strong></li> 
    PJ & HM Deitel<br /> 
    ISBN: 0-13-129014-2<br /> 
    <em>£39.99</em><br /> 
</ul>
```

Specifically, *your list item ends prematurely.* I'd be surprised if it rendered correctly in any browser.

The general rule of thumb is, suspect yourself, not the tool.

Try this, then get back to us:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>JAVA How To Program (6th Ed)</strong><br/>
    PJ & HM Deitel<br /> 
    ISBN: 0-13-129014-2<br /> 
    <em>£39.99</em></li>      
</ul>
```

Comment: You sir!.... ARE A GENIUS. Thanks a bunch seems to have fixed it nicely!. Thinking that the list tags created bullet points, i naturally assumed that i had to end it on the first line where i required only the one bullet point. Cheers in advance :)

Comment: I'm still surprised that an editor like VS2010 allows errors like that. I would have thought it would correct it. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

You have errors. Correct the errors first, then come back here.

Also, if that is all your code, it will be displayed in quirks mode by the different browsers. And different browsers have different quirks! Please make sure to use standards mode.

Also, which version of VS is this? Different versions of the VS have different browsers built in. For instance VS2005 has IE6 built in.

Comment: its not the entire code as ive left the remainder of the tags above. Microsoft visual studio 2010 ultimate. Basically in firefox its showing up that i do not need a break tag for the first line of each list, but in visual studio i do according to its design view.

Comment: Wait, VS2010 allows you to put plain text inside an `ul` but outside of any `li`s? That's odd, I'll have to test that.